# How to stop music from starting if app is in background?

Tags: android, media-player, opengl-es-2.0, glsurfaceview

OK, I've spent 2 days on this almost and getting nowhere, so posting here in hope that someone can come up with a solution of sorts!

In my app, I kick my music off in my **onSurfaceChanged** method.  Seems a pretty good place to do it, as it will start after all of my resources have loaded.

Everything works perfectly, *except*..... if the user presses the **home** key *before* everything has finished loading, then the app (as one would expect) happily goes into the background, but **onSurfaceCreated**, **onSurfaceChanged**, and an initial call to **onDrawFrame** are still initiated... therefore, my music starts playing even though the app is in a 'paused' state and the user can't see it.

I understand that this (calling of the 3 callbacks listed above) is normal behaviour and the GLSurfaceView won't actually pause until it hits **onDrawFrame** - in a way this is good because even if the user presses home, things can continue loading in the background, but it's not good for my music problem!

I've tried starting my music from within **onResume** but the first time the app runs, everything isn't yet setup.  So I've had to put a check in place for null - therefore it only works on **subsequent** launches, (ie, from a paused state).

Any ideas **very** welcome!!

Comment: stop the music in the onpause of your activity

Comment: @IllegalArgument, I'm already doing that- the problem is that if the user presses the home button *before* the music starts playing (and therefore onPause runs *before* the music starts playing) it's effectively calling stop on music that hasn't yet started. The call to start the music then happens after this and the music happily kicks off.

Comment: then check for something like music.isPlaying() then music.pause or music == null do nothing else pause

Comment: check on boolean variable for the app in Resume or Pause.
If pasue then not play music.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a boolean value to ensure that the app is user-facing before starting to play your music.

In `onSurfaceChanged` :

```
if(canPlay) //Do what you need to play the music
```

In `onResume`:

```
canPlay = true;
```

In `onPause` :

```
canPlay = false;
```

EDIT - Or use this mechanism in other forms if necessary. If you are playing your sound through GL, you might want to set a boolean value somewhere else. The key is turning the mechanism off in onPause, and on in onResume.

Comment: Nice.  I've no idea how I missed this.  I tried everything else but never thought to use a simple Boolean :-)